# Unit testing an external HTTP request in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I have the following method:

```
  private async Task<Result> TryGetResult (string request)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient(); 
            var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(request);
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                var body = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var deserializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(body);
                return deserializedResult ;
            }

            if ( result.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429 )
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                return await TryGetResult(request);
            }
        }
```

This takes in this string request:
`var request =  $"https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/address/json ... //(private keys omitted)`

I want to unit test the method and stub out the request so that I don't make a real call. I have limited experience unit testing C# and am struggling to work out how to stub this? Please can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have tried looking at similar articles and googling but cannot find the stubbing of a string request like this and wonder if I'm going in the wrong direction with trying to test?

Answer (score 1):

You should allow for injection of a `HttpClient` from the constructor of the class containing `TryGetResult`

```
public class YourClass // might want to implement IDisposable?
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public YourClass()
       : this(new HttpClient());
    {
    }

    public YourClass(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(client));
    }
}
```

From there, I would suggest mocking the `HttpClient` with
[RichardSzalay.MockHttp](https://github.com/richardszalay/mockhttp). That way you can control the full response.